# Use angular directive as attribute of custom directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to edit this gentleman's fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Wijmo/ywUYQ/) to add ng-click functionality to panes.

My goal is to add an ng-click function to the pane directive so when this is clicked the action specified runs.

Example:

```
<tabs>
    <pane ng-repeat="candy in candies" title="Tasty {{candy.name}}" ng-click="addChocolate(candy)">
</tabs>
```

You will see in the snippet that the **pane** directive works by calling **addPane** in the *tabs's controller* adding itself to it's pane list. The **tabs** directive is responsible of handling the *click event* and showing the correct *pane*. So..... any ideas?

Here's a snippet as shown in the fiddle:

```js
angular.module('components', [])
  .directive('tabs', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {},
      controller: ["$scope",
        function($scope) {
          var panes = $scope.panes = [];

          $scope.select = function(pane) {
            angular.forEach(panes, function(pane) {
              pane.selected = false;
            });
            pane.selected = true;
          }

          this.addPane = function(pane) {
            if (panes.length == 0) $scope.select(pane);
            panes.push(pane);
          }
        }
      ],
      template: '<div class="tabbable">' +
        '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">' +
        '<li ng-repeat="pane in panes" ng-class="{active:pane.selected}">' +
        '<a href="" ng-click="select(pane)">{{pane.title}}</a>' +
        '</li>' +
        '</ul>' +
        '<div class="tab-content" ng-transclude></div>' +
        '</div>',
      replace: true
    };
  })
  .directive('pane', function() {
    return {
      require: '^tabs',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        title: '@'
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
        tabsCtrl.addPane(scope);
      },
      template: '<div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{active: selected}" ng-transclude>' +
        '</div>',
      replace: true
    };
  })
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="components">
  <h3>BootStrap Tab Component</h3>
  <tabs>
    <pane title="First Tab">
      <div>This is the content of the first tab.</div>
    </pane>
    <pane title="Second Tab">
      <div>This is the content of the second tab.</div>
    </pane>
  </tabs>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what exactly the question is?

Comment: @RobertAKARobin how to add the ng-click directive to the pane so that when clicked it executes such ng-click's function

Answer (score 1):

When your directive returns the HTML for your pane, `ng-click=...` isn't being compiled by Angular. You can use the `$compile` service to compile the pane directive's output HTML, so that Angular can register your callbacks as handlers for the `onclick` event.

The output HTML would be handled like this: `$compile(html)(scope)`, within a link function.

Comment: This sounds right! Sadly I'm new to angular. Can you plz walk me through it ? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
.directive('pane', function() {
return {
  require: '^tabs',
  restrict: 'E',
  transclude: true,
  scope: {
    title: '@',
    paneClick: '=',
    paneClickAttr: '='
  },
  link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
    tabsCtrl.addPane(scope);
  },
  template: '<div ng-click="paneClick(paneClickAttr)" class="tab-pane" ng-class="{active: selected}" ng-transclude>' +
    '</div>',
  replace: true
};})


<pane title="First Tab" pane-click="addChocolate()" pane-click-attr="candy">
```